# How to make page take whole browser window?

Tags: html, css

I only recently started looking into bootstrap. I have created a very simple page, and I want it to take all of the window instead of just wrapping to content size. I am focusing on webkit browsers. I want the content to take 100% of the page height-wise and width-wise. Width is already done but I have trobules with taking 100% of height.

I tried the following solution from a similar question on Stack Overflow:

```
  html{
    min-height: 100%; /* real browsers */
    height: auto !important; /* real browsers */
    height: 100%; /* IE6: treated as min-height*/
  }
  body {
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 100%; /* real browsers */
    height: auto !important; /* real browsers */
    height: 100%; /* IE6: treated as min-height*/
  }
```

But it has no effect.

This:

```
  html{
    height: 100%;
  }
  body {
    background-color: #FFF;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

Takes up too much space - it gets too tall and scrollbar appears.

What should I do to achieve my goal?

Full code is here: https://gist.github.com/LucasSeveryn/d1590bcafbf6e23b1239

Comment: sorry, overread it..it´s late over here...deleted answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution is use `height: 100%` with `overflow: scroll` property.

Comment: Yes that's the one I used in the end.

Answer (score 2):

The key to 100% height is that you need a wrapper div around all of your content that is also set to `min-height: 100%`. Here is your code with the extra wrapper added in (I gave it a red background for demo purposes):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>ActRecognitionWeb</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/backbone.js"></script>
    <script src="js/underscore.js"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  <style type='text/css'>
  html{
    height: 100%;
  }
  body {
    background-color: #FFF;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
  }

  .wrap {min-height: 100%; background: red;}

  #login-screen
  {
    background-image: url('img/login_background.jpg');
    padding-top: 40px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 60px;
    padding-right: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 200;
    line-height: 30px;
  }

  .container-fluid
  {
   padding-top: 40px;
   height: 100%;
   padding: 60px;
   padding-right: 200px;
   margin-bottom: 30px;
   font-size: 18px;
   font-weight: 200;
   line-height: 30px;
 }

 #login-sidebar
 {
  text-align: right;
  opacity:0.8;
  padding-top: 10%;

}
.navbar .brand
{
  padding-left: 30px;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  color: inherit;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <div class='navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top'>
      <div class='navbar-inner' style="height: auto;" >
        <a class="brand" href="#">ActRecognition</a>
        <ul class="nav" data-bind="visible: loggedIn()">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Summary</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Challenges</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Routes</a></li>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav pull-right" data-bind="visible: loggedIn()">
        <li class="dropdown" >
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span data-bind="text: userName"></span>
            <b class="caret"></b>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Settings</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Log Out</a></li>
          </ul>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/knockout-2.2.1.js'></script>
<script src='js/viewModel.js'></script>

</html>
```

There's a great nuts and bolts tutorial on this here:

http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?171943-CSS-FAQ-Tips-etc-Please-read-before-posting!&p=1243541#post1243541

with a simpler solution if you are just targeting IE8 and above.

Comment: That seems to work for me. Why do you say it doesn't work? What are your expectations? What do you expect to see if the page is taller than the viewport?

Comment: When the page is taller, I expect to see a scrollbar. This is what I see with your solution: http://i.imgur.com/mLQMM0c.png

What I would like to see, is the box that contains the picture extended fully to area of the browser.

Comment: The thing to realise here is that only the wrapper div can be 100% tall, so you'd either have to put that background image on the body or the wrapper div. That link I posted explains the limitations of 100% height, which browsers weren't really designed for. But the later version, for IE8 and above, might be more flexible too in terms of backgrounds.

Comment: So nothing inside the wrapper can be 100% tall?

Comment: No, not with that kind of setup. There might be other options, though. What do you actually need to achieve? Do you have a screen shot of the layout you want?

Comment: Something like this: 
http://i.imgur.com/ZzCM1mK.jpg

This is a splash screen for login, and I turn divs on and off through knockoutjs.

Comment: If you just want a background image to cover the screen, I would put the image as a background on the body element and use `background-size: cover`. Not sure you need height 100% at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use jQuery

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    $('body').height(windowHeight);
});
```